# Is it possible to share App Store Analytics with another Apple ID?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I've created an app on behalf of a customer and uploaded it to the App Store. The customer is keen to see the analytics for their own app (things like impressions, conversion rate, total downloads, etc.) and I can see these on my Apple Developer dashboard.

Is there a way I can give them access to that part of my dashboard so that they can see their own analytics on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invite people as "Team Members" to view your applications. Here is Apple's guide on how to do that:

[Manage your team : Invite team members](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-your-team/invite-team-members/)

> 1. In the top navigation of your developer account, click “Program resources.” Under “Additional resources,” click “Users and Access.”
> 2. Click the add button (+).
> 3. In the dialog that appears, enter the user’s first name, last name, and email address.
> 4. Under Roles, select the user’s role as Admin or Developer.
> 5. Click invite.